# Estimating Successful Combinations of Basketball Players

Tags: self-study, correlation

Suppose we have to analyze sports data (from our school 's informal basketball data).  We have data for all games from the 2019 season, for each game we know which players were playing and which players were absent, and whether the team won or lost. We do not have the actual score of the game. We also don't have any information on individual player scoring. We only know which players were active for which game, and if the game was won or lost (I know that this far from ideal, no data on opponent team, player height/weight, etc.). Also, there are no substitutions, all players play the full game.

The prof wants us to think of ways we where we can find out combinations of players that play well together and result in more wins (i.e. when those players are there, the final result is a win - e.g. filter on rows where certain players are active, and calculate the percent of games won) and which combinations of players that play poorly together and result in less wins. The prof is also interested in knowing which players are "piggybacking" (players who only appear to win a lot when stronger players are there).

**Question:** If there are 10 players, each game could have potentially 2^10 possible combinations of players! I was thinking someone could try to play "Jenga" with the data (e.g. take some random combination of players, filter on the rows where those players played and calculate the win percentage - then remove one player from the filter, and compare the win percentage) ... but there are WAY too many combinations!

**Is there some way which will allow us to try and answer the prof's question about successful and unsuccessful combinations of players? In other words - which groups of players are more strongly correlated with higher win rates?**

Thanks!

**Note:** Sample Data

```
score <- c("won", "lost")



  score = sample(score, 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))

Player1 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
Player2 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
Player3 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
Player4 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
Player5 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
Player6 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
Player7 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
Player8 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
Player9 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
Player10 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
game_id = 1:10000

my_data = data.frame(game_id, Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4, Player5, Player6, Player7, Player8, Player9, Player10, score)

 game_id Player1 Player2 Player3 Player4 Player5 Player6 Player7 Player8 Player9 Player10 score
1       1       1       0       0       1       0       0       1       0       1        1   won
2       2       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1        1  lost
3       3       0       1       1       0       1       0       0       1       1        0  lost
4       4       1       0       1       0       1       1       0       0       1        0   won
5       5       1       1       0       0       0       1       1       1       0        1   won
6       6       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0       1        0   won
```

Comment: You would have to check $2^{10}=1024$ combinations. That is not much, is it?

Comment: IIUC, "piggybacking" means that there are players that don't play well but are part of a lot of wins because of other players, really good ones, that they play together with. Correct? I wonder how to properly define this...

Comment: @ Frank : thank you for your reply! Perhaps 1024 combinations might not be too many - but I was anticipating a situation where if there were 25 players, 10^25 would be far too many combinations ....

Comment: @ Frank: Yes! That's how I would define "piggybacking"!